# Non-greedy wildcard "ignored"

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-greedy

I got the following situation:

```
...    
preg_match('/#(.+?):(.+?)#/im','partA#partB#partC:partD#partE#partF',$matches);
...
```

after the execution $matches becomes

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => #partB#partC:partD#
        [1] => partB#partC
        [2] => partD
     )
```

Wouldn't it be normal for `$matches[1]` to become `partC` if I use the non-greedy wildcard `?` ? Am I missing something?

I managed to solve it by using `'/#([^#]+?):([^#]+?)#/im'` as the pattern, yet a pertinent explanation would be great to clear out the clouds.

Thanks.

Comment: You can actually use `'/#([^#:]+):([^#]+)#/'`. The main point is that *lazy* quantifier does not guarantee the shortest match, and regex engines (be default) process a string from left to right. Once a valid symbol is found, the rest of the pattern is tried from the left-most position to the right. So, `partB#partC` is OK for `.+?`.

Comment: To well understand, a regex engine search the string from left to right and try to succeed at each position in the string.

Comment: I see in your regex `#` to `:` to `#`. Which matches 'abc`############################################################################# : #`def'. It is you that see's `# : #`. The reason is that's what you want to see, it's human nature.

Comment: Really, there is no indication anything is wrong here. It's the perception by you that this is not right.

Comment: Thanks sln, you made my day :) . That's right, I believe I was seeing things that in fact were not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense when you think about the underlying theory behind regular expressions.

A regular expression is what is known as a [finite state automaton (FSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). What this means is that it will, in essence, process your string one character at a time from left to right, occasionally going backwards by "giving up" characters. In your example, the regex sees the first `#` and, noting that the `#` isn't participating in any other parts of the pattern, starts matching the next token (`.+?`, in your case). It does that until it hits the colon, then matches the next token (again, `.+?`). Since it's going left-to-right, it'll match up to the first hash, and then stop, because it's being lazy.

This is actually a common misconception - the `?` modifier for a quantifier isn't *non-greedy*, it's *lazy*. It'll match the minimum possible string, *going left to right*.

To fix your original regex, you could modify it like this:

```
/.+#(.+?):(.+?)#/im
```

What this would do is use a greedy match before the last hash before the colon, forcing the first capture group into only using the stuff between that hash and the colon. In the same vein, that group wouldn't need the lazy modifier either, yielding a final regex of:

```
/.+#(.+):(.+?)#/im
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting out the non-greedy / lazy difference. It really makes sense when put like this.

Comment: @Radacina: If an answer is helpful, typically on SO you would mark it as _the_ answer to your question, using the checkmark button next to the voting arrows. This helps others to find the answers to their questions, because then they don't have to go hunting through the entire answer section of a question.

Answer (score 1):

Capture group 1 is looking for `#` then anything (excluding new lines) until the first `:`. So `partB#partC` makes sense.

Your modifiers also aren't doing anything. You have no case sensitive letters and you aren't using anchors.

You can see how your regex processes here, https://regex101.com/r/iS0lW9/1.

Comment: Yeah, I understand now why it treated it like this and it makes sense. Thanks for the note on the modifiers.